# Can I create "Solution" level items in a Visual Studio Project Template?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, templates

There's a lot of great information on MSDN dealing with creating Visual Studio templates. I've been specifically working through a Multi-Project Solution (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308(VS.80,printer).aspx)

I have everything working in my template (4 projects + 2 Solution Folders - 1 for Tests, and 1 for Libraries that I'm referencing). I have no problem adding projects, or solution folders through the template, but I've hit a wall trying to add dll's and other resources that are not in a specific project, they are just solution level items.

Has anyone dealt with this before? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to do the same thing for a while now and have had no luck finding a native way to do it.  The way I am doing it currently is having a custom project template that adds the items to the project and then through a VS Wizard associated with that template using convention to move the files to the solution level and removing them from the project level.

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet showing how you did this? 

I'm having a really hard time finding the correct syntax to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This hack might be 10 years late, but thought I'd add it anyway. Its less convoluted than creating a VS Wizard to drive the operation of adding solution level items.

Basically I add a dummy project to the multi-project solution template, named "_SharedFiles".

In the other projects that need links to any of these files, I update the [project].csproj to simply refer to the file in the **shared files** dummy project.

```
<Link Include="..\_SharedFiles\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs" />
```